# Is there a plugin for visual studio 2008 that will allow you to use Linq in a watch window?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, debugging

I am working in Visual studio 2008 and would like to be able to use Linq in a watch window.

Is there a tool that will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used this addin personally, but it looks like it does what you are asking for through an extended immediate window (instead of the watch window). [Extended Immediate Window](http://extendedimmediatewin.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you're asking for, but something like this might help you when debugging  LINQ:

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net)